# Gatsby: pass state to links in markdown files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am working on a Gatsby site. There is a side navigation tree to navigate to all the articles backed by Markdown files (using `gatsby-transformer-remark`). In order to maintain the state of which tree nodes are expanded when navigating to different pages, I include some state with the `navigate` call in my navigation tree component:

```
      navigate(node.href, {
        state: {
          expandedNodes
        }
      });
```

This works great. When going to the next page the state of the tree is maintained.

However, my problem is when I want to link from one Markdown article to another. When I click the link, it navigates to the correct page, but the state of the tree is lost.

Is there any way I can get that state to be passed to the link in the Markdown file?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to solve a similar issue to this as well. I found the gatsby plugin `gatsby-plugin-catch-links` which maintained the state of the app (including the tree), since it "catches" the links found within markdownn files and wraps them with the Link component provided by Gatsby instead of an "a" HTML tag.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-catch-links/

Comment: So how do you pass through state in a markdown link?